# Flask: How to fix Mysql Operational Error 2013?

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am so confused by this. I have no problem running the app.py in local server but when I deploy my app in my website It throws me error on line

```
cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM info WHERE email=%s', (email,))
myinfo = cursor.fetchone()
cursor.execute('SELECT sum(transaction) FROM transactions WHERE email=%s', (email,))
sum = cursor.fetchone()
cursor.execute('Select * from process WHERE email=%s ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 20', (email,))
process = cursor.fetchall()
```

The full traceback of error is this

```
App 4080945 output:   File "app.py", line 145, in userpage
App 4080945 output:     
App 4080945 output:   File "/opt/alt/python38/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
App 4080945 output:     res = self._query(query)
App 4080945 output:   File "/opt/alt/python38/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
App 4080945 output:     db.query(q)
App 4080945 output:   File "/opt/alt/python38/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 259, in query
App 4080945 output:     _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
App 4080945 output: MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
```

If I place the

```
cursor.execute('Select * from process WHERE email=%s ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 20', (email,))
process = cursor.fetchall()
```

to the beginning of the function, everything works but if I place this to the end like shown in the code above it throws that error.

I am not sure why this is happening. The placement of the `select * from process` is not a problem in my local server but a problem in the website server.

What is my fix?

Mysql config

```
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'myserver'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'admin'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'password'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'app_db'
mysql = MySQL(app)
```

Comment: Have you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/error-lost-connection.html

Answer (score 0):

Fix it by requesting my hosting provider to increase packet size. As I was on a shared sever I had to request them to increase it.